# Ubuntu 18.10 Hybrid Graphics Dual Monitor issue

Tags: nvidia, asus, gpu-driver

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my Asus ROG GU501GM laptop and it was working fine with my external HDMI monitor with nvidia enabled in prime-select.

Today, I selected prime-select Intel and rebooted because I wanted some more time to do some work without the laptop plugged in. I got about 3 hrs worth of work done, which I was impressed!

However, I ran nvidia-select nvidia and rebooted with my external HDMI monitor plugged in but now it doesn't work. Only the laptop display is working.

The nvidia card is working as I can see from nvidia-smi and glxinfo, but no HDMI output.

Here are some things I tried:

1. reinstalled driver - didnt work
2. reset BIOS - didnt work
3. unplugged HDMI and replugged - didnt work

Any ideas how to get the external monitor working in using HDMI?

Comment: Please provide the output of `inxi -SMG -! 31 && ubuntu-drivers devices`. Take a look to the output of `journalctl -b0 -p4`.

Comment: $ inxi -SMG -! 31 && ubuntu-drivers devices
Error 22: Unsupported option: -!
Check -h for correct parameters.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C20sv00001043sd0000185Ebc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

Comment: $ nvidia-smi 
Sat Jan 26 17:24:35 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 415.27       Driver Version: 415.27       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|

Comment: the last comand journalctl -b0 -p4 produced a TON of output and I cant paste that here. But I looked for EE errors and nothing jumped out at me

Comment: Please provide the output of those commands by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1113144/edit) using [Markdown](https://commonmark.org/help/). Also `ubuntu-drivers list` maybe show you other driver that works well with GDM3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the issue... 
GDM3 is not compatible with nvidia-prime. After testing and testing and going to nvidia-dev forums, most people with this issue install lightdm and the problem is fixed.

Apperently, there is a bug in GDM3 and nvidia-prime or something like that. In either case, its fixed using lightdm

Thanks for the reply!
Joe